# What does the CARICOM Regional Task Force on Crime and Security (CRTFCS) do?

Tags: international, crime, caricom, caribbean

I've seen this CRTFCS mentioned in various places, [e.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Security_System)

> The RSS initially started as a US instrument to combat the spread of communism in the Caribbean region. As of 2001, the RSS further cooperates with the CARICOM Regional Task Force on Crime and Security (CRTFCS).

So what exactly is the charter of the CRTFCS? And what do they do in practice?

Answer (score 2):

Q: *What does the CARICOM Regional Task Force on Crime and Security (CRTFCS) do?*

The website for the [CARICOM Regional Task Force on Crime and Security](https://caricom.org/category/regional-task-force-on-crime-and-security/) has been offline since December 4, 2023, due to an application breach. (The full page was never saved to the Internet Archive. There is a saved xml feed.) It seems reasonable that the current responsibilities are the same as when it was established.

[xml Feed](https://web.archive.org/web/20230528174533/https://caricom.org/category/regional-task-force-on-crime-and-security/feed/) from May 28, 2023, concerning recent activity.

> Under the theme, ‘Violence as a Public Health Issue – The Crime Challenge’, the symposium seeks to promote dialogue and regional action aimed at violence reduction and crime prevention. At least seven CARICOM Heads of Government will participate in the symposium which Dr. the Hon. Keith Rowley, Prime Minister of the Republic of Trinidad and Tobago, and Lead Head with responsibility for Crime and Security, will chair.
>
> At the Forty-Fourth (44th) Regular Meeting of the Conference of Heads of Government of CARICOM held in Nassau, The Bahamas, from 15-17 February 2023, Heads of Government agreed that the Government of Trinidad and Tobago would host a special symposium to consider crime as a public health concern. This follows the decisions taken by the Heads of Government in 2019, 2020, 2021 and 2022 to convene such a meeting, the plans for which were delayed by the onset of the COVID-19 pandemic.
>
> The Region’s method of addressing crime and violence from a social prevention perspective as well as a criminal justice perspective has been the traditional approach for a number of years.
>
> The conventional approach of the criminal justice system focuses on retribution, imprisonment, rehabilitation and restoration, with the goal of restoring harmony and reintegrating people into society. However, this has resulted in consistently escalating levels of crime and violence which have been an ongoing concern of CARICOM Heads of Government for several years.
>
> Given CARICOM’s deep concern about the unprecedented levels of crime, Heads of Government resolved to increase focus on the determinants of crime by taking a public health approach which would first identify the causal factors and preventions where possible, followed by interventions.
>
> The Regional Symposium will emphasise a holistic system approach, particularly a whole of Government and whole-of-society approach, involving and collaborating with all relevant agencies, organisations and sectors at different levels, including civil society, business, community, families and individuals.
>
> The topics to be discussed over the two days include: Violence and Health in the Region; Crime and Violence: A Public Health Approach; Mental Health; Transnational Organised Crime; Using Litigation to Protect Gun Violence – Global Action on Gun Violence; Trans-Border Crime; Education and Youth, Domestic Violence; Economic Inequalities as the Driver of Crime and Violence; Community approaches- Restorative Justice; Sports and Mediation; and the Judicial Perspective- Legislation and Juvenile Justice Reform.

##### Background (Task Force origin and recommendations.)

The CARICOM Regional Task Force on Crime and Security was established in 2001 ["to identify, analyze and recommend a way forward in dealing with the fundamental causes of Crime and Security threats in the Region."](https://www.caricomimpacs.org/about) In July 2006, the recommendations were used to create the [Caribbean Community (CARICOM) Implementation Agency for Crime and Security (IMPACS)](https://www.caricomimpacs.org)

[Crime and Security on CARICOM Agenda](https://sflcn.com/crime-and-security-on-caricom-agenda/), February 12, 2006.

> The Task Force presented over one hundred recommendations from which a number was identified for a renewed regional initiative.
>
> The Task Force also made recommendations for establishing multi-sectoral National Commissions on Law and Order and forming a regional research network that will bring together the University of the West Indies (UWI) and other institutions with research capabilities.
>
> National Crime Commissions would drive implementation of National Crime Control Master Plans, integrating law enforcement, social crime prevention, legal issues and international cooperation as part of an all-embracing approach to crime reduction.
>
> The Task Force identified unemployment, inequality, social marginalization and inequality, poverty, the illegal drug trade, the trafficking in firearms, corruption and the ineffectiveness of the existing criminal justice systems in the region as factors contributing to the crime problem in the region. Other major security threats stem from criminal deportees, growing lawlessness and the vulnerability to terrorism.